# Why do Type Member bounds stop working when self types are involved

Tags: scala, generics, typing

Say I define some traits with a self-type. Both the traits and the self type have a abstract type member. The abstract type member in the self-type should be overridden by the self-type in the trait.

```
trait Foo{
  type My
  def make:Seq[My]
}

trait Component {
  type My
}

trait Bar extends Foo { this:Component =>
  override type My <: StuffDoer

  def len = make.map(_.doStuff)

  class StuffDoer(str:String) {
    def doStuff = "blah"
  }
}
```

This doesn't work and gives the error:

```
Error:(20, 24) value doStuff is not a member of Bar.this.My
    def len = make.map(_.doStuff)
```

It seems that `My` inside of `Bar` is not necessarily a `StuffDoer` type but why? What are the exact bounds on `My` inside of `Bar`? Does `Component` override it's type boundaries?

What is even more strange is when I change `override type My <: StuffDoer` inside of `Bar` to:

```
override type My = StuffDoer
```

then suddenly everything compiles. How come???

Answer (score 0):

If class `StuffDoer` has method `doStuff` then all subclasses do as well but not all subtypes do. For example `Nothing` and `Null` are subtypes of `StuffDoer` but you can't call `x.doStuff` on variable `x` of type `Nothing` or `Null`.